# Using Group Actions to determine the different colourings of a grid

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups, polya-counting-theory

I am trying to find the number of different colourings of an $n \times n$ grid using $m$ colours by using group actions. The set that I am acting on is the set of $n^2$ ‘tiles’ within the square grid.

I am finding it hard to understand this problem but this is my plan:

I want to define a group action that rotates the grid and then I will calculate the number of different orbits using Burnside’s Lemma.

Once I have the number of different orbits, say $k$. The number of colouring that are the same under rotation is $m^k$.

The problem is I’m struggling to grasp the concept of what the group I choose is doing.

- Does the group I decide determine the orbits? Or does the group not act on the set at all until I define how it acts in some way?

My idea was to let the subgroup of $D_4$, $\langle r \rangle$, be the group as this is the rotation subgroup of the symmetries of a square $D_4$.

- How do I know how this subgroup acts on the set of tiles and in the way I intend it to?

Comment: All I need is a bit more understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Let $X(m,n)$ denote the set of all possible $m$-colorings of an $n\times n$-grid. This is a set of $m^{n\times n}$ elements. You want to count the number of elements of $X(m,n)$ up to rotations. So you want to count the number of orbits of the rotation action on $X(m,n)$. That is; the rotation group $\langle r\rangle$ acts on $X(m,n)$ in a natural way; the rotation $r$ maps an $m$-coloring of the $n\times n$-grid to the $m$-coloring you get by rotating the grid. I hope this clarifies the situation a bit.

Comment: My lecturer said I could consider the set of $n^2$ tiles as the set and then consider the orbits of each tile under rotation. He said then to count the number of orbits,$k$ and then $m^k$ will give the number of colourings that stay the same under rotation by 90 degrees. I suppose I’d count the number of ones that stay the same every 180 degrees and number of ones that change every time under rotation. Then add all those up to get total number of different colourings I assume???

Comment: Is that not what you’re doing? Why is his approach wrong I’m very confused.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here, which is very understandable. It is late here, however, so all I will do is recommend the explanations given by Arthur, and perhaps to try a few small examples before trying the general case. I.e. try working it out for $m,n\leq3$. This is small enough that you can draw everything you need to draw (don't go drawing *all* grids!) and see the patterns that you need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, forget the dihedral group and go right for the cyclic group $C_4$ (or $\Bbb Z_4$ if you prefer that). That removes one layer of abstraction.

We pick the group of rotations of the square, because that is the precise group of symmetries that we consider "not to change" the grid in our final answer. We want to consider grids that are rotations of one another to be the same, so the group of rotations is what we're going to look at. If we also considered mirrorings to produce "the same grid", then we would use the dihedral group $D_4$, since that is the group of "rotations and mirrorings".

Let $M$ be the set of the $m^{n^2}$ differently coloured grids (where we *do* consider rotated grids to be distinct; this is the easy one to count). Then each of the four elements of $C_4$ induces a bijection $M\to M$, intuitively given by rotations by $0^\circ, 90^\circ, 180^\circ$ and $270^\circ$ respectively. The product of elements in $C_4$ corresponds to compositions of rotations. This collection of bijections, and the correspondence between these two operations is called a $C_4$-group action on $M$.

Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $M$ defined by $x\sim y$ iff one of these four bijections takes $x$ to $y$. Then the equivalence classes are called *orbits* of this action. We are after the number of such orbits.

The vast majority (at least for large $m$ and $n$) of these equivalence classes will have size $4$. So $\frac{m^{n^2}}{4}$ is a decent first approximation to the final answer. However, some will have size $2$ and some will have size $1$, and trying to count the number of orbits of each size directly is a pain.

That's where burnside's lemma comes in. Instead of focusing on the number of equivalence classes of each size, this lemma leverages the orbit-stabilizer theorem to change focus entirely. We now take each of the four bijections, and count the number grids that are mapped to themselves:

- For the $0^\circ$ rotation, that's $m^{n^2}$, as each grid is mapped to itself.
- For the $90^\circ$ rotation, that's going to depend on the parity of $n$. If $n$ is even, there are $m^{n^2/4}$ grids that are mapped to themselves by this rotation, while for odd $n$, the answer is $m^{(n^2 + 3)/4}$.
- For the $180^\circ$ rotation, and even $n$, there are $m^{n^2/2}$ grids that are sent to themselves, while for odd $n$ there are $m^{(n^2+1)/2}$ grids.
- For the $270^\circ$, the answer is the same as for the $90^\circ$

Now just take the average of these four numbers (in each case picking the right one depending on whether $n$ is even or odd), and you get the number of orbits.

Comment: You have the base and exponent reversed throughout.  The base should be $m$.

Comment: @RobPratt Right you are. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m just getting very confused now. One lecturer at my university told me to let the set I act on be the set of tiles and not the set of $m^{n^2}$ colourings. He said we should do this because what we want to do is colour orbits of the tiles. Why is the set we act on in your answer the set of colourings and not the set of tiles. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: He said to me the $n$ x $n$ grid part is sort of a distraction as what we’re working on it actually permutations of the $n^2$ tiles. Are these different approaches or are they the same approach?

Comment: @Anteater23 No, the group definitely acts on the set of coloured grids, not on the tiles. However, it definitely helps to see each grid as a mosaic of tiles when counting in my bullet points. In  the $90^\circ$ case, for instance, we see that each time we fix the colour of one tile, the $90^\circ$ rotation will "move that tile" over to another tile, which is then forced to have the same colour if we want the rotation to not change the grid whatsoever. And then we see that this newly coloured tile is moved to a third tile, which has to have the same colout, and so on.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now one more ‘logical’ question. Is it the group acting on the set or do we not need to define a function (a group action) that explains how the group works with the set of colourings. This is the confusing part of me. How does a group just act on a set? Is this obvious?

Comment: Also I think my lecturers approach was consider the $n^2$ uncoloured tiles of the grid and find out their orbits and then colour them according to their orbits.

Comment: @Anteater23 Each element of the group yields a bijection from the set to itself. This correspondence must be formally defined for the notion of "group actions" to make sense, yes. But appealing to intuition and saying "the group acts by rotation" is usually considered enough in a case like this. Given a coloured grid, you _know_ what a $90^\circ$ clockwise rotation will do to it, don't you?

Comment: @Anteater23 And yes, that approach is how I would count the numbers for the bullet points. That was what I was trying to explain by my earlier comment about tiles moving over. Just with different words.

Comment: @Anteater23 When I counted the number of grids unchanged by the $0^\circ$ rotation, by the $90^\circ$ rotation, by the $180^\circ$ rotation and the $270^\circ$ rotation, I put them in a list because I thought it looked nice and clear. That list has black dots indicating each of the four parts of my counting. Those big black dots are called "bullet points". When I do this counting, I think about an uncoloured grid, and then try to count the number of ways to colour it in, always keeping in mind that it should stay exactly the same after, say, a $90^\circ$ rotation.

Comment: So after I colour a corner using one of the $m$ colours, each of the other four corners _must_ have the same colour, since a $90^\circ$ rotation takes one corner to the next. If all the corners aren't the same, the grid will be changed after rotating $90^\circ$. And for each tile I colour, there are three more tiles that must have the same colour (except the center tile, if there is one).

Comment: Thank you for your many explanations. I’ll try to go through it all again a few times and see if I can finally ‘get it’.

Comment: One question I have that is key to me understanding this is: If I want to consider 180 degree rotations only I assume the group I let act on the set of colourings is $C_2$. Similarly, if I want to consider the reflections about a line of axis I would use the group $C_2$ also. Hence I ask, how can this one group $C_2$ be acting on the set of all colourings and correspond to different things each time?

Comment: Surely it must be different groups acting on the set of colourings or else we would obtain the same orbits each time?

Comment: @Anteater23 Yes, the groups are different and the group actions are different. You already know that rotating something $180^\circ$ and mirroring something about an axis are two different actions that yield different results. You don't really need me to tell you that. The groups are different, and give rise to different group actions on the set. Although the two groups are isomorphic, as they are both cyclic of order $2$.

Comment: So what we are working with is not $C_2$ but in fact $<r>$ for rotation, $<s>$ for reflection and $<r^is>$ for reflection in another axis?

Comment: Or does $C_2$ be the group every time and you vary how the group acts on the set of colourings?

Comment: @Anteater23 While $\langle r^2\rangle$ and $\langle s\rangle$ are both cyclic of order $2$, and thus isomorphic to $C_2$, they do induce different actions on our set of grids. So yeah, it's $C_2$ every time, but $C_2$ can act on a set in many different ways.

Comment: When I say let $<r>$ act on the set of colourings. Don’t I have to say how it acts and prove it’s a group action using the two axioms? It’s not exactly set on stone how a Group plays with a set unless you say how? I am correct?

Comment: @Anteater23 That is correct. You have to say how, and technically you have to prove that it is indeed a group action. To more experienced algebraists, however, saying "it acts by rotation" is enough to cover both, as "by rotation" says how, and showing that it fulfills the axioms is about as easy as such a proof can be.

Comment: I’m not too experienced so I think I’ll do that as an exercise. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry one final note. Could I use only the $C_2$ group to perform all these actions by just defining the group action by $C_2$ on $M$, $f:C_2X M \rightarrow M$, differently. For example define $f: (g,m) \mapsto R_{360/o(g)} m$ for rotation in 180 degree turns and define $f:(g,m) \mapsto S^{o(g)-1}m$ for reflection about the diagonal?

Comment: @Anteater23 Yes, you can use the same group (not just isomorphic groups, like $\langle r^2\rangle$ and $\langle s\rangle$, but _actually the same group_) to define multiple different group actions, for instance by defining one group action $C_2\times M\to M$ to act by rotation, and one action $C_2\times M\to M$ to act by mirroring across a horizontal axis. For instance. The only problem is you have chosen to call both actions $f$, and that's a bad thing. Different functions should have different names.

Comment: However, compartmentalizing by using two different (but isomorphic) groups, and having them both act the way you would naturally think about the groups in the first place ($r^2\in D_4$ is _meant_ to be a rotation by $180^\circ$) will make things easier.

Comment: Ok thank you. My lecturer said if I wanted to consider rotation of the ‘square annuluses’ within the nxn grid (for odd n) instead of rotations of the rigid nxn grid then I would use the subgroup $C_{16}$ X $C_8$ $\leqslant S_{25}$ as the group in the case of n=5. If I was to consider your method instead would the group be $<r>$x<r>$?

Comment: Also why can you just decide that the first group in the product acts on the outer most square annulus and the the 2nd group acts on the middle square annulus.

Comment: @Anteater23 There is nothing to "just decide". The rotation group of the outer annulus is $C_{16}$, and the rotation group of the inner annulus is $C_8$ (assuming you by "rotate" mean something more akin to "slide", like in a slide puzzle). Combining them gives $C_{16}\times C_8$. That's all there is. If you have two groups each doing separate things that don't interfere, the product works nicely, with each factor having the sole responsibility of its own actions. That's in some sense the _definition_ of product. I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: Should the product $C_{16}x C_8$ in this case be acting on a product of sets then. Say $A x B$ where $A$ is the set of colourings on the outer annulus and $B$ the set of colourings in the inner annulus?

Comment: I then find the number of different colourings of each square annulus and multiply then answers together?

Comment: @Anteater23 No, they both act on $M$. The objects they act on are $5\times 5$ grids of coloured tiles. That has never changed. But since the actions commute (i.e. don't "interfere" with one another), you can combine the two actions to make the product of the groups act on $M$. If they do interfere with one another, you have to combine the groups in a different way (for instance, the dihedral group is the combination of rotation and mirroring in this sense).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I’ve managed to understand this and I’ve been able to work out how you got those numbers in your post. I’m not going to apply to find number of different colourings up to rotation and symmetry now!

Comment: @Anteater23 I honestly think we have strayed far enough away from the original question that that warrants its own question post.

Answer (score 1):

[OEIS A047937](https://oeis.org/A047937), which I authored, provides a formula for all $n$ and $m$:
$$\frac{m^{n^2} + 2 m^{n^2 + 3(n \mod 2))/4} + m^{n^2 + (n \mod 2)/2}}{4}$$

You have the correct group.  The denominator 4 is the number of elements in the group.  The first term in the numerator corresponds to the identity element.  The third term corresponds to the 180-degree rotation.  The second term corresponds to the other two rotations (90 and 270).

The $n \mod 2$ appears because in the odd $n$ case, the center square is always fixed.  To better understand this, you might investigate $n=2$ and $n=3$ separately.

Comment: Could you explain why this is the right group? The subgroup $<r>$ doesn’t act on the set of tiles does it? Do I have to define a function to make it act on the set of tiles? Sorry, but this is what I’m really confused about!

Comment: The group doesn't act on the set of tiles; it acts on the set of all $m$-colorings of $n\times n$-grids.